# How Can I Create two window in scalafx?

Tags: scene, scalafx

I want two windows in a single scene using scalafx with my GUI. Is there any specific method in scalafx by which I can create that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for? A scene can be put into a stage/window, not a scene into a window. Do you want to open two separate stages/windows?